# Bounded Generic Types in Method Parameters C#

Tags: c#, generics, bounded-types

**Question**: Does C# support bounded generic types in method parameters? If so what is the syntax?

**Context**: I am writing a utility method that sorts a `Dictionary` on the values within the dictionary. Therefore the values in the `Dictionary` must implement the `IComparable` interface.

**Attempt(s)**: The code below takes a `Dictionary`, get the list of `KeyValuePair`, sorts on the `Value` and then returns the top keys in the dictionary as reported by their values.

```
private string[] getTopWords<T , U>(Dictionary<T, U> similarWordsAndWeights)
{
    var myList = similarWordsAndWeights.ToList();

    myList.Sort((firstPair, nextPair) =>
    {
        return -firstPair.Value.CompareTo(nextPair.Value);
    }
    );
    var dictionary = myList.ToDictionary((keyItem) => keyItem.Key, (valueItem) => valueItem.Value);
    return createStringArrayFromGenericList(dictionary.Keys.ToList().GetRange(0, 10));
}
```

However this code will not compile as `U` is not "guaranteed" to implement `IComparable`. The syntax `private string[] getTopWords<T, U : IComparable>` will also not compile.

I could type check to see that my `U` implements `IComparable` however I would rather not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So shortly after going through writing my question I looked on MSDN and found an article on [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) which I had been through already however halfway down the page I found the answer that I was looking for. Here is the code for the solution:

```
private string[] getTopWords<T , U>(Dictionary<T, U> similarWordsAndWeights) where U : IComparable
{
    var myList = similarWordsAndWeights.ToList();

    myList.Sort((firstPair, nextPair) =>
    {
        return -firstPair.Value.CompareTo(nextPair.Value);
    }
    );
    var dictionary = myList.ToDictionary((keyItem) => keyItem.Key, (valueItem) => valueItem.Value);
    return createStringArrayFromGenericList(dictionary.Keys.ToList().GetRange(0, NUMBER_OF_WORDS_TO_RETURN));
}
```

It appears that you do the bounding declaration AFTER the parameters. I was looking for something before (having a Java background) and of course was not able to find anything. Amazing what one can do on google with just a few extra minutes...

I thought it wise to share my solution as I was not able to find anything specifically on SO and it may be helpful to others that end up searching for the same thing.

Comment: Just a heads up that in C# these are called generic type constraints and you should be able to find a lot of other information about them on StackOverflow and other sites by searching those terms.

Comment: Thank you @jam40jeff I'll remember that so I can find relevant information next time.